# How to wait for more approves in Microsoft flow?

Tags: power-automate

When one participants approved flow continous, BUT i want to wait till all of 3 participants approves! How it could be done?

Comment: Yes i did, you need to do next things: 1.root action,2.Three(or less/more) paralel actions-send approval email, one for each approver, 3.add a condition and click edit in advanced mode then type this:@and(equals(body('Send_approval_email')?['SelectedOption'], 'Approve'),equals(body('Send_approval_email_2')?['SelectedOption'], 'Approve'),equals(body('Send_approval_email_3')?['SelectedOption'], 'Approve'))---> this is AND operator, checks all conditions individually, and on the and choose you action if conditions is yes or no...thats it, i hope it helps

Comment: If you have found the answer, please post that as a complete answer rather than in the comments.